# Passing javascript array from view to controller in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am passing data from view to controller to post to database, I am using a **database first approach of the entity framework**, so models is set up ok,
I have an empty array `var formArray = [];`. Data from input fields is captured as

```
var OPDNo = $('[name= OPDNo]').val();
var Re = $('[name= re]').val();
var Le = $('[name= le]').val();
```

in my view, I have input variables which I have put them into a **formData{}** as

```
var formData = {
'OPDNo': OPDNo,
'VAFRE': Re,
'VAFLE': Le
};
```

The OPDNo, Re, Le are both input fields. I am passing data using Ajax as below:

```
if (formData != null) {
                $.ajax({

                    url: '/EMR/SaveVisionScreening',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ formArray: formData, selectValues: selectValues }),
                    success: function () {
                        showNotification("Record Saved Successfully", "info", true);

                    }
                });
            }
```

In my controller,

```
[HttpPost]
        public void SaveVisionScreening(string formArray, string [] selectValues)
        {
//Code...

         }
```

When I debug, the controller returns a null on **string formArray**, I have also set ***traditional: true ** but it is still null.
I have checked some solutions here but it has not helped me solve it.

Comment: SaveVisionScreening(string OPDNo,string Re,string Le)  passed this as single parameter  and also  change in ajax function

Comment: Please I would appreciate a snippet code for your suggestion

Comment: I am passing alot of data, more than 30, that is why i opted for an array

Comment: ok then SaveVisionScreening(string []  formArray, string [] selectValues) try this one string []

Comment: @Pravin I have changed to suit your suggestion but it is returning any value, it is still null

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that represents your inputs rather than having to have two input parameters. For example, you could create a class like so:

```
 public class FormData
 {
    public string OPDNo { get; set; }

    public string VAFRE { get; set; }

    public string VAFLE { get; set; }

    public string[] selectValues { get; set; }
 }
```

And then modify your JS code like so:

```
        var selectValues = [];
        selectValues.push('item1');
        selectValues.push('item2');

        var formData = {
            OPDNo: 'OPDNo',
            VAFRE: 'Re',
            VAFLE: 'Le',
            selectValues: selectValues
        };

        $.ajax({

            url: '/home/SaveVisionScreening',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(formData),
            success: function () {
                showNotification("Record Saved Successfully", "info", true);

            }
        });
```

Then your controller method like this:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public void SaveVisionScreening(FormData formData)
    {


    }
```

See the result below: [image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, though I should mentioned that I am using database-first approach with entity framework

Comment: That does not have any relationship with your question. Perhaps you should let me know why you are talking about entity framework here since your question was 'How to pass javascript array from view to controller

Answer (score -3):

I finally got a way out, thanks for everyone, I got challenged and I did more search and I found this [method](https://mestanzasoft.wordpress.com/2018/03/05/pass-data-from-asp-net-mvc-view-to-controller-with-ajax-and-json/), I thought it is important to share so this would do

For my case I had

```
var formData = {
'OPDNo': OPDNo,
'VAFRE': Re,
'VAFLE': Le
};
```

declare a variable to hold the object data in json form by

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(formData);
```

Handle the data using Ajax by doing the following:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: '/EMR/SaveVisionScreening',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'JSON',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     data: { dataPost:jsonData, select}
     success: function () {
     showNotification("Record Saved Successfully", "info",true);

     }
  });
```

In your controller, do this

```
[HttPost]
public ActionResult SaveVisionScreening( string dataPost, string [] selectValues)
{
//Your code for deserializing the json objects goes here and saving data

}
```

It is good to understand that the data passed is now a json object and not an array, hence the reason you should use a **string data type**